# Making a C17 circuit in C++

Tags: c++, circuit, digital-logic

I'm trying to simulate a C17 logic circuit in C++ using a Library called [LibLCS](http://liblcs.sourceforge.net/). [Click here](http://liblcs.sourceforge.net/xor_using_and_or_not.html) to see an example of a digital circuit made with this lib. But isnt working. I cant compile the code and I have no idea why.

```
#include <lcs/lcs.h>
#include <lcs/nand.h>
#include <lcs/simul.h>
#include <lcs/tester.h>
#include <lcs/changeMonitor.h>

// All libLCS constructs are defined under
// the namespace lcs.

using namespace lcs;


int main()
{
  Bus<1> a, b, c, d, e, ga, gb, gc, gd, ge, gf;

  Nand<2> nandGate1(ga, (a,b)), nandGate2(gb, (b,d));
  Nand<2> nandGate3(gc, (c,gb)), nandGate4(gd, (gb,e));
  Nand<2> nandGate5(ge, (ga,gc)), nandGate6(gf, (gc,gd));


  ChangeMonitor<5> inputMonitor((a,b,c,d,e), "Input", DUMP_ON);
  ChangeMonitor<2> outputMonitor((ge,gf), "Output", DUMP_ON);

  Tester<5> tester((a,b,c,d,e));

  Simulation::setStopTime(4000); // Set the stop time.
  Simulation::start(); // Start the simulation.

  return 0;
}
```

I got the following compilation error:

```
g++ -o c17 c17.cpp /tmp/cc5TeFfF.o: In function main':
c17.cpp:(.text+0x50a): undefined reference to lcs::Simulation::setStopTime(unsigned int)'
c17.cpp:(.text+0x50f): undefined reference to lcs::Simulation::start()' /tmp/cc5TeFfF.o: In function lcs::Bus<(1)+(1)> const lcs::Bus<1>::operator,<1>(lcs::Bus<1> const&) const':
c17.cpp(.text._ZNK3lcs3BusILi1EEcmILi1EEEKNS0_IXplT_Li1EEEERKNS0_IXT_EEE[_ZNK3l‌​cs3BusILi1EEcmILi1EEEKNS0_IXplT_Li1EEEERKNS0_IXT_EEE]+0x75):
```

And many more...

Comment: Where is it failing?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest. It gives me about a hundred erro lines. [leonardoalves@localhost c17]$ g++ -o c17 c17.cpp
/tmp/cc5TeFfF.o: In function `main':
c17.cpp:(.text+0x50a): undefined reference to `lcs::Simulation::setStopTime(unsigned int)'
c17.cpp:(.text+0x50f): undefined reference to `lcs::Simulation::start()'
/tmp/cc5TeFfF.o: In function `lcs::Bus<(1)+(1)> const lcs::Bus<1>::operator,<1>(lcs::Bus<1> const&) const':
c17.cpp:(.text._ZNK3lcs3BusILi1EEcmILi1EEEKNS0_IXplT_Li1EEEERKNS0_IXT_EEE[_ZNK3lcs3BusILi1EEcmILi1EEEKNS0_IXplT_Li1EEEERKNS0_IXT_EEE]+0x75):  and so on..

Comment: @Aracthor you right, it's just a link problem. Solved it.  Thank you very much bro.

Comment: I'll do it, It seen I have to wait a minute to do that, but i'll. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your errors trace that you gave us in comments, I may tell you that you forgot to link your program with your lib.

If your lib is called `liblcs.so` or `liblcs.a`, so add this flags to your g++ compilation :

```
g++ -o c17 c17.cpp -llcs -L"path to the lib folder"
```

It should works. Or at least it should solve this problem.

Comment: You right bro. Solved it. Thank you very much. I'm trying to give you vote but I doesn't have reputation enough for this u.u I marked the "V" with the green color.

Comment: yes, I can. Already marked with green :D I would like to vote but I cant.